# How to boot into the command line?

Tags: boot, command-line, text-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to autologin in text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175248/how-to-autologin-in-text-mode)

How can you boot directly into the command line with Kubuntu? I've tried searching on Google but all I can find is related to Ubuntu.